# Confused with BEM naming convention - need correction?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

I'm creating ecommerce site for learning purposes and I've got problem. I'm using BEM naming convention and I don't know if I'm doing it good, here's my code:

```
<div class="product product--miniature" data-id-product="{$product.id_product}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute}" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <figure class="product__thumbnail">
    <div class="product__badges">
      <span class="badge badge--{$flag.type}">{$flag.label}</span>
    </div>
    <img src="{$product.cover.medium.url}" alt="{$product.cover.legend}" data-full-size-image-url="{$product.cover.large.url}">
  </figure>
  <div class="product__info">
    <h3 class="product__name" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}">{$product.name}</a></h3>
    <div class="product__prices">
      <span class="price" itemprop="price">{$product.price}</span>
      <span class="price--discount">{$product.regular_price}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have biggest issue with the product badges and product prices, I think something's wrong over there?

Comment: everything seems fine to me. As long as you avoid using many IDs ( and under no circumstances use duplicateIDs ) and use classes and name your elements suggestively , i can't see the problem. For more detailed answers you should take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see to consider here is the use of the `price` and `badge` block classes. If they can exist on their own (outside of the `product` block) then what you have is fine. However, if they will only ever exist inside a product then you might like to change them to `product__price` and `product__badge`